# Spring security - authenticate via controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to create a simple controller for clients to login. In response I would like to send them a number (lets say its an id of the player)

I already have a custom spring security authetication mechansim.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public int login(@RequestBody loginDTO loginDTO, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException,
    ServletException {

this.authenticationProvider.manualAuthentication(
                         loginDTO,
                         request,
                         response);

/hard coded id for the example purpose
return 123;

}
```

Apparently now the client ajax call receives an error! (the data.responseText contains the login page in an html. WHY?)

A lead on solving this issue:

When i comment the line:

```
this.authenticationProvider.manualAuthentication(
                         loginDTO,
                         request,
                         response);
```

It works as intended (ofcourse without the authentication taking place, but the result data is delivered to the client sucessfully) ,  So apparently the authentication call is somewhat transforms the response object in a way

Any ideas?

Comment: your hard coded id is an int and the method should return `NGToken`. Please post a correct code snippet as now it wouldn't even compile.

Comment: also if responseText contains login page that probably means the login was unsuccessful, and user was redirected back to login page.

Comment: Thanks soulcheck, iv'e fixed my snippet. so is there a way to not redirect ?

Comment: What is `authenticationProvider.manualAuthentication` supposed to do ? And do you verify it does it effectively ?

Comment: authenticationProvider.manualAuthentication works as intended effectivly, it does a couple of custom things i need in my project like extracting parameters from the loginDTO that are not solely username\password